# How to take screen shot of UIImageiew using image with aspect fit?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, image, screenshot

I want to take screen shot from imageview with image aspect fit. I tried with this code but it will not get actual result. And I want get screen shot of actual image size

```
func captureScreen() -> UIImage
    {
        let layer =  self.layer
        let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, scale);
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {return UIImage.init(named: "")!}
        layer.render(in:context)
        let screenshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                
        return screenshotImage!
    }
```

This is what I get
[image]
I want to screen shot with actual with full actual image size
Please help me

Comment: Your image size is layer.frame.size?  What is self.layer?

Comment: Yes that is my imageview layer @ElTomato

Comment: you can achive it using `imagview.contentMode = .aspectfill`

Comment: That screen shot in my question is already took from sets .aspectfill @RB's

Comment: @KamleshShingarakhiya but here you mentioned `aspect fit` in your question.

Comment: and you can also achieve this by setting imageview frame as image frame.

Comment: An image of an image at full size is the image itself.

Comment: @RB's I also tried that but can not get result

Comment: @matt Can you please help me with an example? Please

Answer (score 1):

```
    //MARK:- Calculate ImageviewWith image size
    func convertImageViewToImagebounds(image:UIImage, imageView:UIImageView) {
            if image.size.height > image.size.width {
                let ratio = image.size.height / image.size.width
                let newWidth = imageView.frame.size.height / ratio
                imageView.frame.size = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: imageView.frame.size.height)
                imageView.center = CGPoint(x: viewImgViewContainer.frame.width / 2.0, y: viewImgViewContainer.frame.height / 2.0)
            }else if image.size.height < image.size.width {
                let ratio = image.size.width / image.size.height
                let newHeight = imageView.frame.size.width / ratio
                imageView.frame.size = CGSize(width: imageView.frame.size.width, height: newHeight)
                imageView.center = CGPoint(x: viewImgViewContainer.frame.width / 2.0, y: viewImgViewContainer.frame.height / 2.0)
            }else {
                let ratio = image.size.width / image.size.height
                let newHeight = image.size.width / ratio
                imageView.frame.size = CGSize(width: image.size.width, height: newHeight)
                imageView.center = CGPoint(x: viewImgViewContainer.frame.width / 2.0, y: viewImgViewContainer.frame.height / 2.0)
            }
    }
```

take a look here:

this function will return your `imageview` size as `image` have and viewImgViewContainer is parent view of imageview to set imageview in center.

Comment: Thanks. It will get () size